# Python CGI gives me errors that I cannot fix alone

Tags: python, forms, post, filesystems, cgi

I have a webpage that can upload files to my python server with CGI, but when I submit the file it gives me this error.

```
::1 - - [30/Jan/2021 18:30:40] b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\upload file\\cgi-bin\\python_script.py", line 8, in <module>\r\n    if fileitem.getvalue("filename"): \r\nAttributeError: \'bytes\' object has no attribute \'getvalue\'\r\n'
::1 - - [30/Jan/2021 18:30:40] CGI script exit status 0x1
```

HTML code:

```
<html> 
<body> 
   <form enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "cgi-bin/python_script.py" method = "post"> 
   <p>Upload File: <input type = "file" name = "filename" /></p> 
   <p><input type = "submit" value = "Upload" /></p> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

CGI code:

```
import os 
import cgi, cgitb

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileitem = form.getvalue("filename")
  
# check if the file has been uploaded 
if fileitem.getvalue("filename"): 
    fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename) 
      
   #read and write file into server
    open(fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.getvalue("file").read())
```

I'm not sure how to fix the problem, I have added getvalue() to some of the code, but my error didn't get fixed

full server logs:

```
Serving HTTP on :: port 8080 (http://[::]:8080/) ...
::1 - - [30/Jan/2021 18:30:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [30/Jan/2021 18:30:39] "POST /cgi-bin/python_script.py HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [30/Jan/2021 18:30:39] command: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -u "C:\Users\ETORE\Desktop\upload file\cgi-bin\python_script.py" ""
::1 - - [30/Jan/2021 18:30:40] b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\upload file\\cgi-bin\\python_script.py", line 8, in <module>\r\n    if fileitem.getvalue("filename"): \r\nAttributeError: \'bytes\' object has no attribute \'getvalue\'\r\n'
::1 - - [30/Jan/2021 18:30:40] CGI script exit status 0x1
```

Other notes:
I have put the filesystems tag because it has something to do with files like writing the uploaded files to the folder that the app is in.

Comment: As the error tells you, `fileitem` is an object with the type of `bytes` that object type doesnt have an attribute / method called `getvalue`

Comment: hmm if i remove the if statement and getvalue on the after code then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, but I cannot get the file extension and name.

CGI Code:

```
import uuid
filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
import os 
import cgi, cgitb
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileitem = form.getvalue("filename")
open( "uploads/" + filename + ".bytes", "wb").write(fileitem)
```